изменить значение в определенных ячейках в массиве
Дан массив 3*3 нужно заменить значения в определенных ячейках, пишу код:
table = [[0] * 2] * 3
table[0][0] = 123
table[0][1] = 456
print(table)

При запуске кода получаем ответ:
[[123, 456], [123, 456], [123, 456]]
а нужно получить:
[[123, 456], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
Как это можно решить, лучше без пересоздания массива?

[[0, 0] for _ in range(3)]

@Amgarak отвечает на вопрос почему это происходит, но ответа не дает

@ff Без пересоздания массива не получится. В нём уже лежат повторяющиеся ссылки. Только правильное создание списков тут может помочь - через for in range, а не через умножение.

@ff понимая проблему, теперь можете поискать решение, например в поиске по данному ресурсу. (Спойлер, ответ вам уже дали чуть выше моего комментария)
